# What is the best way to generate income from mobile games?

Tags: game-design, marketing

As the title states, what is the best way to get income from mobile games?
(taking into consideration that creating the games only costs a lot of time and the games are relatively simple)

As I see it, there are multiple ways of getting money from mobile games,

1. Selling them for a fixed price (seems like a high threshold for potential buyers)
2. In-game purchases (I can imagine this only works for several types of games, I don't see this working well for monopoly unless you like really fancy hotels ;)
3. Ingame advertisements / sponsorships

Which way will most likely bring the most profit?

Comment: Impossible to say which would be best. It depends on how each is implemented, the game they're implemented for and the market trends at the time. If there was a certain "best" way, everyone would be doing it that way and there wouldn't be any alternative.

Comment: @Byte56, You assume everyone has the foresight and will to both understand and implement a "best way".  For all we know, there *is* a "best way", but the curiosity and arrogance of man will never acknowledge such a thing.

Comment: What is the reason for the downvotes on this question? Is it not relevant enough to game development?

Comment: @extropic_engine most likely because people feel this has no definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer you seek is, all 3.

You should release a free version of your game with ad support. 
Offer a paid version that removes ad support and adds a few bells and whistles. 
and if it makes sense to do so, have features where you can purchase in-game content.

But to answer the question about how to profit, that is much harder.

To profit you need to consider things not related to the game.

- Time spent on the project
- How much it will cost (art, design, programming, API's, hardware, software, licenses)
- Marketing: this is a big factor, you have to get noticed in the sea of existing games
- maintenance

and many other things related the the SDLC (software development life cycle)

I hope this gets you started on your journey! 
And remember: If the game isn't fun who is going to want to play it?

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for and defiantly the right road most traveled. Can't say I like it (I miss the days of games being completely free and created just for fun).

Comment: I don't mind people making money off of their work. I just want everyone to be making something they can be proud of, not just copying the most successful and hoping to get a cut of the pie.